# installation of r java shows error 'not a valid Win32 application'

Tags: rjava

I have a problem while loading `rjava`:

```
Downloading GitHub repo SantanderMetGroup/loadeR.java@master
from URL https://api.github.com/repos/SantanderMetGroup/loadeR.java/zipball/master
Installing loadeR.java
"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.3/bin/i386/R" --no-site-file --no-environ --no-save  \
  --no-restore --quiet CMD INSTALL  \
  "C:/Users/Dhruv/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpEvMOHF/devtools28bc1ec54d4d/SantanderMetGroup-loadeR.java-14fcdf1"  \
  --library="C:/Users/Dhruv/Documents/R/win-library/3.4" --install-tests 

* installing *source* package 'loadeR.java' ...
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
Error: package or namespace load failed for 'rJava':
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...)
  error: unable to load shared object 'C:/Users/Dhruv/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/rJava/libs/i386/rJava.dll':
  LoadLibrary failure:  %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

Error : package 'rJava' could not be loaded
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'loadeR.java'
* removing 'C:/Users/Dhruv/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/loadeR.java'
In R CMD INSTALL
Installation failed: Command failed (1)
Downloading GitHub repo SantanderMetGroup/loadeR@master
from URL https://api.github.com/repos/SantanderMetGroup/loadeR/zipball/master
Installing loadeR
"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.3/bin/i386/R" --no-site-file --no-environ --no-save  \
  --no-restore --quiet CMD INSTALL  \
  "C:/Users/Dhruv/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpEvMOHF/devtools28bc49114ff9/SantanderMetGroup-loadeR-fb63df6"  \
  --library="C:/Users/Dhruv/Documents/R/win-library/3.4" --install-tests 

ERROR: dependency 'loadeR.java' is not available for package 'loadeR'
* removing 'C:/Users/Dhruv/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/loadeR'
In R CMD INSTALL
Installation failed: Command failed (1)
```

Comment: Is Java installed on your system and did you set the path variable? What operating system do you use?

Comment: Thanks problem is solved now. I updated Java version